# How to disable copy and paste in webform textarea?

Tags: entities, javascript, webforms

Is there a way to disable pasting into a webform textarea field?

I've created a textarea field called: my_words and I want to forbid anyone from copying and pasting text into this field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tested this code, but a quick Google search suggests the following (obviously change #Password to the ID of your textarea field).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Password').bind('cut copy paste', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a drupal question. But anyway, if you disable Javascript, you still can paste into your textarea with the JS solution from [chapabu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3119/chapabu). The proper solution is to have the textarea disabled. `<textarea disabled="disabled">`
Or something like that: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#disabled 
Note that disabling a form field doesn't necessarily prevent someone from submitting a value through DOM manipulation. It just tells the browser not to accept input.

But why would you prevent someone to copy-paste values into it? Seems strange. Maybe I write my words in a word-file with spellchecking and then want to copy my words into your field? Why not? Do you want a security solution, that someone can not copy-paste words, that are not his into your textarea? As long as there is not a solution that prevent us from lying you will fail ;-)

Comment: From an UX point of view I agree here.  I'm not sure of any use case why it would be useful to not allow users to paste values into a text area.  If it's specific text that's being displayed, I'd probably go in favour of a #markup field anyway to be honest :)  I suppose a better formatted question is needed for a definitive answer.

Comment: It is indeed a drupal question since the textarea is in a Webform and I thought that I could use the Webform conditional module to do it. Anyway, about prevent copy/paste, in my case it makes sense since the webform is used in a 'memory test evaluation' then copy/paste would be like cheating the evaluation. I know that by disabling javascript the jquery solution is useless but the average age of the user is around 70 year-old and disabling js is not in their day to day chores list.

Comment: @chefnelone it's not a drupal question because you're question is about how any HTML Form works, the Form and this copy paste issue is the same in any web framework or browser. Users here are being nice by answering your question regardless. Your lack of web experience makes you think it's a drupal issue. The proper way to do this 'memory test evaluation' to disallow copy and paste is to create your testing application in Flash or Java for the web; those environment(s) let you control things like copy/paste in the runtime. But, at least you have a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is the only best choice to disable text editing,

http://kvcodes.com/2014/03/disabling-textbox-cut-copy-and-paste-operations/